# Install a new feature in a wix patch

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a new feature added to a wix patch. If i run the patch directly by double clicking it, the new feature gets installed correctly.

If I apply the patch using a batch file with the following command, new feature doesn't get installed. "%windir%\System32\msiexec.exe" /p MySoftwarePatch.msp REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=omus

I am guessing that using REINSTALL=ALL doesn't allow a new feature to be applied. Is there a way I can use msiexec, have the REINSTALL=ALL and install the new feature properly?

Comment: Would you clarify the issue? Your first section says "If i run the patch directly by double clicking it, the new feature gets installed correctly." so it's not clear what the issue is. It seems you just don't need to set REINSTALL on the command line because Windows sets it automatically so you don't need to.

Comment: The issue is when i use REINSTALL=ALL in the command line, the new features don't get applied. As a workaround, I am including COMPADDLOCAL in the command line with one of the components' GUID so that the feature gets installed.

Comment: My question comes down to why bother with REINSTALL=ALL if it works without it? Leave it off the command line and it works, yes?

Comment: Ok, I thought REINSTALL needs to be included whenever we apply patches. That's why I included it. If it's unnecessary, that solves my problem. Thanks.